# Broadcast intent delivery with DataWedge is not working in android app?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, datawedge

I am trying to get barcode in my app using DataWedge in Motorola MC40N0. I created a profile in DataWedge. Intent action is android.intent.action.DEFAULT and Intent category is android.intent.category.MAIN and selected intent delivery as broadcast intent. Activity in manifest is:

```
 <activity
     android:name="com.myproject.activities.ScanActivity"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait"
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.MAIN" />
     </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Following is the code which i have in my ScanActivity:

```
 IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.DEFAULT");
 BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            String data = intent.getStringExtra("com.motorolasolutions.emdk.datawedge.data_string");
            System.out.println("scanned data: "+data);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("exception in scanning: "+ex);
        }
    }
};
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

But i am not getting anything. Is there something wrong with setting or code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Piscean : are you getting Broadcast from custom DataWedge profile? have you done with this ? 

If yes so can you please guide me.

Comment: yes i am getting it. Check out the answer i have accepted. It worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the same datawedge bug as [described here](https://github.com/BlueFletch/motorola-datawedge-cordova-plugin/issues/3).

Try to remove intent category in your datawedge profile config.